# Total Sales by Month for each country

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, group-by

I have table with `SELLERS(Seller_ID, Country, Month, Sales)`. I want to write a query to extract the total sales, month in which minimum sales occurs and month in which maximum sales occurs by country.

**Update:**

Sample Data:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Oracel <> MySQL. Please specify what RDBMS you are using. Also, Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Please go through this link once: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT SELLER_ID,
       COUNTRY,
       SUM(Sales) AS TOTAL_SALES,
       (SELECT Month FROM SELLERS WHERE Sales = (SELECT MIN(Sales) from SELLERS WHERE Country = Outer_Table.Country) LIMIT 1) AS MONTH_MIN,
       (SELECT Month FROM SELLERS WHERE Sales = (SELECT MAX(Sales) from SELLERS WHERE Country = Outer_Table.Country) LIMIT 1) AS MONTH_MAX
FROM SELLERS AS Outer_Table
GROUP BY Outer_Table.Country
ORDER BY Outer_Table.Seller_ID
```

You may try it [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6193d2/3) with your posted data.

Comment: It's not working. Gives an error: Subquery returns more than 1 row.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32036e/1

Comment: Can you at least post a sample of your data where my query fails? My query works well with a simple table that I've created my self.

Comment: I've updated my question. Please have a look sample data.

Comment: @JigarGorakhiya Thanks. I have updated my answer to fix the error.

Comment: Perfect. It's works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? First calculate `SUM` of sales, and then find out which month has `MIN` and `MAX` value (per month & country):

```
with ss as
  (select country, 
          month, 
          sum(sales) sum_sales
   from sellers
   group by country, month
  )
select country, 
       month, 
       min(sum_sales) min_sales, 
       max(sum_sales) max_sales
from ss
group by country, month
order by country, month;
```